# Multiple variables in switch-case statement

Tags: c#, html, switch-statement, case

Is it possible to return result from multiple switch statement?

For example i would like to use employee.DepartmentID and employee.StatusID for my case. But how do i include employee.StatusID in this statement? Using and/or operators?

```
                switch (employee.DepartmentID)
            {
                case 1:
                    EMAIL = "abc@gmail.com";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    EMAIL = "abcd@gmail.com";
                    break;
            }
```

Comment: If you are looking for `switch (employee.DepartmentID || employee.StatusID)` then it is not possible.

Comment: that doesn't sound like a viable solution. you can concat the strings `switch(employee.DepartmentID + employee.StatusID`

Comment: So if the department is `1` and the status is `2`, what should happen?

Comment: Can you give an example of what your ideal switch statement would look like? And (building on what @Servy asked) why would departmentID = 1 and Status = 2 be different than departmentID = 2 and status = 2 or departmentID = 1 and status = 1. Basically, what is the benefit you are looking for from the multiple conditions.

Comment: For example if the departmentID is 1 and StatusID is 1 then EMAIL will be abc@gmail.com

Comment: So, you have a separate email for each department based on status? Ok. That we can work with.

Comment: sounds like you should use an If Condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you really need is this.

Use the Switch to determine which department is involved

```
  Switch (DepartmentID)
  {

     case  1:
         Email = classHR.GetEmailAddress(Status);
         break;
     case  2: 
         Email = classMarketing.GetEmailAddress(Status);
         break;
   }
```

Use Static Classes for the different departments (using an interface preferably).

This will give you a better run down than what you are thinking of here.

Comment: don't forget the `break;`

Comment: Thanks updated with the break;